# donot see the option to save the email as a seprate file in sharepoint blog post email enabled list?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a requirement from my client to store the email as seprate file in one of the blog site I have created. when I see the Posts(default from blog site) incoming email settings, i do not see the option save as .eml file. Please help me if there is any workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm think you will probably need to [create an email receiver](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/creating-a-simple-email-receiver-for-a-document-library/). Inside the email receiver, you could save the .eml file separately.

*Edit*

Code from the article:

```
byte[] binaryContent = null;
String mailContent = String.Empty;

using (Stream stream = emailMessage.GetMessageStream())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        mailContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }

    binaryContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mailContent);
    stream.Close();
}

// we overwrite previous files with the same name
SPFile file = folder.Files.Add(url, binaryContent, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Can you please guide me how to save the .eml file in the email receiver.

Comment: Sure thing! If you read the article, it has the code in there to get the email message and save it. I edited my answer to include the relevant code snippet. I would suggest giving it a try. :)

Comment: Hi Again, The code is saving the content from the email into list. In My scenario, I have created a blog and I have email enabled the Posts list. For this list i already have columns and the data is stored in there. Because the blog posts does not have the setting "Store the original Email", I am looking for some kind of code to get the email data and save it as .eml file (may be in document library ).

Comment: I tried adding the code from the article but once i activated the feature, the list is unable to receive the emails. Then I deactivated, the list received the email normally.

Comment: Yikes... I'm not sure. Maybe someone else has an idea. Sorry.

Comment: Be sure that if you want to enable default functionality as well you need to instantiate the base event receiver as well. I.el.. Base.Emailreceived();